# SQL column of sums of multiple rows while keeping all rows?

Tags: sql, select, group-by, sum, nested-select

So I have a query select that outputs something like this:
(the actual results I'm working with is much more complicated but these are the important parts)

```
id   trans
123   5.00
124   6.00
124   7.00
125   8.00
125   9.00
```

I want to create a result like this:

```
id   trans  total
123   5.00   5.00
124   6.00  13.00
124   7.00  13.00
125   8.00  17.00
125   9.00  17.00
```

Basically I want to add a column that contains a total of all the transactions for each id, while still showing all the transactions. I think the solution will have something to do with group by, nested selects and the sum function but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 1):

A [windowed function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_(SQL)) works well for this scenario:

```
select
  *
  ,sum(trans) over(partition by id) as total
from
  myTable
```

[SqlFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9f266/2)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you want:

```
SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY group)
```

If the first output is from this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(col) AS trans
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

Then you need this:

```
SELECT id, SUM(col) AS trans, SUM(SUM(col)) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS id_total
FROM table
GROUP BY id;
```

If the first output is from this:

```
SELECT id, trans
FROM table;
```

Then you need this:

```
SELECT id, trans, SUM(trans) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS id_total
FROM table;
```